# Export results from JSON in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to fetch auto suggestions from Youtube using the following call:

```
await fetch('https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=skrillex&callback=suggestCallback')
.then(response => console.log(response))
```

This call obtains the following JSON as a result:

```
"suggestCallback && suggestCallback(["skrillex",[["skrillex",0],["skrillex bangarang",0],["skrillex make it bun dem",0],["skrillex scary monsters and nice sprites",0],["skrillex cinema",0],["skrillex live",0],["skrillex first of the year",0],["skrillex sicko mode",0],["skrillex kyoto",0],["skrillex remix",0]],{"k":1,"q":"bEJKh2TVzWqSICI3U3xEdXTC00g"}])"
```

I am struggling however to convert this result to an array of the "actual suggestions". For example, I want to store the JSON obtained above in the following format:

```
let myArray = ["skrillex", "skrillex bangarang", "skrillex make it bun dem", "skrillex scary monsters and nice sprites", "skrillex cinema", "skrillex live", "skrillex first of the year", "skrillex sicko mode", "skrillex kyoto" ,"skrillex remix"]
```

What would be a viable solution in order to achieve this?

Comment: Your result is actually JSONP, you should be able to strip the non-JSON part of it before running `JSON.parse()` on it with regular expressions. With the value, you can get to the path you're interested in, that is `[1]`, and then use `Array.prototype.map()` to convert it to the data structure you're interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to use regex to filter a json response out of the response you get, and then create an array from that result.

```js
let jsonp = 'suggestCallback && suggestCallback(["skrillex",[["skrillex",0],["skrillex bangarang",0],["skrillex make it bun dem",0],["skrillex scary monsters and nice sprites",0],["skrillex cinema",0],["skrillex live",0],["skrillex first of the year",0],["skrillex sicko mode",0],["skrillex kyoto",0],["skrillex remix",0]],{"k":1,"q":"bEJKh2TVzWqSICI3U3xEdXTC00g"}])';
    
    let myRe = /\[(.*)\]/g;
    let regExGroups = myRe.exec(jsonp);
    let json = JSON.parse(regExGroups[0]);
    
    let myArray = [];
    
    json[1].forEach((element) => {
     myArray.push(element[0]);
    });
    
    console.log('suggestions array', myArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zeonfrost/s7b4aLr6/

But what you really should do is probably define a suggestCallback function [what is jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-and-why-was-it-created)

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

This API you're using is not meant to be used as a regular JSON response, but rather a JSONP, which is a technique created to not only return you a JSON payload as response, but actually it returns executable JavaScript code, based on the request.

You see, on the request URL, `https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=skrillex&callback=suggestCallback` , notice the last parameter on the call, which is the name of the **callBack** to be called automatically, from the response returned JavaScript code.

In this case your callback is named `suggestCallback` which means, the response JavaScript code, expects that there is a function declared with the name `suggestCallback` within the page, which gets automatically called when the response arrives, passing it the correct JSON payload.

To execute this code as a JSONP, the correct code would be :

```
(...)
    <script>
      let myArray = [];

      const url='https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=skrillex&callback=suggestCallback';

      function suggestCallback(j) {
        console.log("myArray is currently ", myArray);
        myArray = j;
        console.log("myArray is now ", myArray);
      }

      function go() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = url;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }
    </script>
(...)
```

So at this point, the only thing you would need to do is trigger the `go()` function from whatever action you want (ex: click of a button, body onload, etc.) and this code, would dynamically create a `<script>` tag, pointing to the API specified by `url` in the example. Of course you could pass the `url` as an argument of a `go(url)` function if for instance some parameters on the URL would be more dynamic.

## Option 2

Let's say you still want to use the `fetch` call as you have it.
In that case, the top part of the code would remain the same, only the `go()` function from my code would need to be changed.

In the new version, you also have 2 options, 1 is to execute directly `eval` which immediately tries to execute whatever JavaScript code you pass as a string to this function, or you can dynamically create a new `<script>` element, setting its `text` property to the JavaScript source to be executed.

The code for the `go()` function would then be :

```
(...)
      function go() {
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.text())
          .then((src) => {
            // eval(src); // you could directly eval the response JS code

            // or you can use the traditional way of creating a script element
            const script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.text = src;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
          });
      }
(...)
```

I wrote this post to explain the expected way how to handle URLs that return JSONP payloads. The previous solutions are what I would consider a workaround, to extract the JSON payload from a JSONP payload, which is not the expected way to handle this kind of calls.

Comment: I removed the rant from your answer *on purpose*, please do not add it back. It's noise and doesn't add anything for readers. If you have a complaint please post on Meta. Thanks.

Comment: I flagged the previous answer, for moderator review, as I think it was deleted unjustifiedly. Although not complete, it contains valid information to the user.